# Spyder: Is it possible to have two rows of file tabs?

Tags: spyder

I'm using spyder with two panels (in column format), and currently, I'm working with a bunch of scripts simultaneously. Unfortunately, the file tabs in the tab bar are squeezed together and I cannot see their names properly. It makes it hard to switch back and forth between scripts effectively. Having the file tabs in two rows would solve this issue, but I couldn't locate where to set this up. Makes me wonder if it's possible in the first place. Does anyone know if it's possible and if yes, where I can find it?

I know about cmd+P/ctrl+P which brings up a list of open files, but this is a lot slower. It would be nice if I could see what the tabs actually say so I can just switch with a single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, it's not possible to have two or more rows of tabs in the editor and it's not something we plan to add in the future, sorry.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's a feature that a lot of people would want to have. Maybe future iterations of spyder may work on that option. I would definitely use it.